# Is it possible to predict a certain numerical value given a DNA sequence using LSTM?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, bioinformatics, recurrent-neural-network

I have 16 letters of DNA sequence. From this 16-letter DNA sequence, there is an output value so called 'Inhibition value' which ranges from 0 to 100. When I tried using LSTM, the prediction only output a constant. Is the problem lies in the code or is it just not a suitable task for LSTM or RNN in general to solve?

I have tried to increase batch size and epochs, make the LSTM deeper, change the number of LSTM units, but none of them works.

I was also wondering whether the labeling method matters or not. I tried to use One-hot encoder at first, but it didn't work. Then, I changed it to LabelEncoder, but it's also not working. Same constant output is produced.

Below here is the code for my model structure

```
def create_model():

    input1 = Input(shape=(16,1))
    classifier = LSTM(64, input_shape=(16,1), return_sequences=True)(input1)
    for i in range(2):
        classifier = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(classifier)
    classifier = LSTM(32)(classifier)
    classifier = Dense(1, activation='relu')(classifier)
    model = Model(inputs = [input1], outputs = classifier)
    adam = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)
    return model
```

If anyone wondering why I use functional API instead of sequential, it is because there is a possible modification where I need to use 2 input variables that needs to be processed independently before concatenating it at the end.

Thank you in advance.